Azure Pipelines - Conditional expansion of a Template
When using Azure Pipelines, I would like to execute a job (expanded from a template), based on the result of the previous job. Is there any way I can do that? What I've tried is the following:
 - stage: deployDev
    displayName: Deploy to Dev environment
    jobs:
      - ${{ if eq(stageDependencies.detectChanges.outputs['sourceChanges.infrastructureSourceChanges.filesUpdated'], True) }}:
        - template: deploy-infrastructure.yaml
          name: deployInfrastructure
          parameters:
            environment: "dev"
      - ${{ if or(succeeded('deployInfrastructure'), skipped('deployInfrastructure')) }}:
        - template: deploy-staging.yaml
          parameters:
            environment: "dev"

And this got me 2 errors:

Unrecognized value: 'succeeded'...
Unrecognized value: 'stageDependencies'....

What I'm interested in is:

run deploy-infrastructure if the output from a previous stage says so;
run deploy-staging if the first job either succeeded or was skipped


You cannot use job status check functions such as succeeded or failed
in template expressions ${{ if ... }} because these values are NOT available at compile time.
Use conditions instead, which are evaluated at runtime.
Example
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - name: detectChanges
    value: 'true'  # <----------- change value to test conditions

stages:
  - stage: detectChanges
    displayName: Detect changes
    jobs:
      - job: sourceChanges
        displayName: Detect changes
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: |
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=filesUpdated;isOutput=true]${{ variables.detectChanges }}"
            name: infrastructureSourceChanges

  - stage: deployDev
    displayName: Deploy to Dev environment
    jobs:
      - job: deployInfrastructure
        displayName: Deploy Infrastructure
        condition: |
          and(
            succeeded(), 
            eq(stageDependencies.detectChanges.sourceChanges.outputs['infrastructureSourceChanges.filesUpdated'], 'true')
          )
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: |
              echo "Deploying to Dev"
              exit 0
            displayName: Deploy Infrastructure
      - job: deployStaging
        dependsOn: deployInfrastructure
        displayName: Deploy Staging
        condition: in(dependencies.deployInfrastructure.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped')
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: |
              echo "Deploying to Staging"
            displayName: Deploy Staging

Please note that the syntax of referencing output variables with dependencies varies depending on the circumstances (e.g. using a regular job or a deployment job, same stage vs different stages, etc) - see the Dependency syntax overview for more details.

Is there any way to use condition together with a template expansion? condition was my first option, but didn't seem to work with template expansion:
    - template: deploy-infrastructure.yaml
          condition: succeeded()
          parameters:
            environment: "dev"


@CosminSD add a parameter for the condition in the template. See Create Configurable and Extensible Jobs. BTW that link is one of the many Azure YAML pipelines guidelines I created some months ago.

@CosminSD, you cannot use condition together with a template expression, but only can put condition in the template yaml. The script by Rui above is working, please check and follow up if you have any queries, thanks.
